# Sending API-requests between two docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ddev

I have running a DDEV-Environment for Magento2, locally on my Mac OSX (Ventura)

https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/quickstart/#magento-2

For testing purpose I included Nifi per docker-compose.yaml inside my ddev project `.ddev/docker-compose.nifi.yaml`

Below you can see the `docker-compose`, which is really minimal at this point. Nifi works like expected, because I can login etc, although it is not persistent yet, but thats a different problem

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:latest
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-nifi
    ports:
      # HTTP
      - "8080:8080"
      # HTTPS
      - "8443:8443"
    volumes:
        # - ./nifi/database_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/database_repository
        # - ./nifi/flowfile_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/flowfile_repository
        # - ./nifi/content_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository
        # - ./nifi/provenance_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/provenance_repository
        # - ./nifi/state:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/state
        # - ./nifi/logs:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
        # - ./nifi/conf/login-identity-providers.xml:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/login-identity-providers.xml
        - ".:/mnt/ddev_config"
```

All I want to do is sending a POST-requst from Nifi to my Magento2 module.

I tried several IPs now, which I got from `docker inspect ddev-ddev-magento2-web` but I always receive "Connection refused"

My output from `docker network ls`:

```
NETWORK ID     NAME                         DRIVER    SCOPE
95bea4031396   bridge                       bridge    local
692b58ca294e   ddev-ddev-magento2_default   bridge    local
46be47991abe   ddev_default                 bridge    local
7e19ae1626f1   host                         host      local
f8f4f1aeef04   nifi_docker_default          bridge    local
dbdba30546d7   nifi_docker_mynetwork        bridge    local
ca12e667b773   none                         null      local
```

My Magento2-Module is working properly, because sending requests from `Postman`to it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want most of what you have. Please remove the `ports` statement, which you shouldn't need at all; if you need anything, you'll need an `expose`. But I doubt you need that in this case?

You'll want to look at the docs:

- [Additional services and add-ons](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/additional-services/)
- [Additional services with docker-compose](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/custom-compose-files/)

Then create a .ddev/docker-compose.nifi.yaml with something like

```yaml
services:
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:latest
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-nifi
    container_name: "ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-someservice"
    labels:
      com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
      com.ddev.approot: ${DDEV_APPROOT}
    expose:
      - "8080"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=$DDEV_HOSTNAME
      - HTTP_EXPOSE=8080:8080
      - HTTPS_EXPOSE=9999:8080
    volumes:
        - ".:/mnt/ddev_config"
```

The name of the "web" container from inside your nifi container will be "web", `curl http://web:8080`, assuming that you have nifi on port 8080.

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but this may get you started. Feel free to come over to the [DDEV Discord channel](https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k) for more interactive help.

Comment: hi @rfay,
with your suggested docker-compose.nifi.yaml config I was not able to access nifi UI. I used mine instead but sent requests to web:PORT and now it works, thanks!